# DataGrid: Resize column: drag anywhere in the column separator, no only in the header

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, resize

I want to be able to resize a DataGrid by dragging the column separator anywhere and not only in the header (which is the default behavior).

How can this be done? Will I have to extend the DataGrid and program it myself? Or is there a simpler way?

Thanks,
Nuno